# Rotation speed setting?

Tags: animation

Just wondering if there is any add on, feature, tool or third party software to set an object too rotate at a certain speed during animations such as making a wheel rotate at 1000 rpm or something like a drill drilling at 150 rpm. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For this you need to do a little math. We need to find out how much the wheel spins withing 1 second.

Let's say you render at 30fps and one rotation equals 360°. First we have convert *rotations per minute* into *rotations per second*. Then we have to convert *rotations per second* into *degrees per second*.

```
1000rpm / 60s = 16.667rps
```

We multiply 360° by 16.667rps to get how many degrees it spins in a second.

```
16.667rps * 360° = 6000°ps
```

The wheel spins ~6000° per second. To find out how many degrees it spins in a frame, divide the spins per second (6000°) by the number of frames per second (30fps).

```
6000° / 30 = 500°
```

The wheel needs to spin 500° per frame to complete 1000rpm.

To do that, go to frame 1 and set a keyframe at 0° rotation. Then set a keyframe at 500° rotation on frame 2. To make it continue speaking, location the rotation fcurve in the graph editor, select it and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation*. (See [this related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132431/30849).)

You can also use [this online calculator](https://www.convertunits.com/from/RPM/to/degree/second).

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of that, will try to use that more in the future

Answer (score 3):

**For constant rpm use a driver**

Similarly to answer by [@DrachenSeele](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139131/15543) some simple maths.

The frame rate of your blender scene.  *Test in python console, where `C = bpy.context`*

```
>>> fps = C.scene.render.fps / C.scene.render.fps_base
```

Convert revs per minute to revs per frame

```
>>> rpm = 150
>>> rps = 150 / 60
>>> rpf = rps / fps
```

Make this an angular velocity.  Note that blender uses [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as its native unit of angle. (displayed as degrees if that is the unit set in scene units)  One revolution is 2pi radians.

```
>>> angular_velocity = 2 * pi * rpf
>>> angular_velocity
0.6551529985521121
```

Ok now add a simple driver `0.6552 * frame` (*rounded for example sake*) to a rotation value, an axis of euler rotation or an angle of angle-axis rotation.

The expression above can be typed directly into the field with a hash prefix to designate it as a driver  `#0.6552 * frame` The variable `frame` is known to the driver namespace and is the value of `context.scene.frame_current`.

[image]
*Driver added to default cube to spin around X axis at 150 rpm.  Notice the sampling rate of animated gif makes this look sluggish due to the [wagon wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect)*

To avoid the wagon wheel effect try setting the rpm to a prime number  near the target rpm (eg 151 instead of 150) or add a slight randomness to the driver.

```
0.655153 * frame + noise.random()
```

*`mathutils.noise` module is known to driver namespaces as `noise`*

Also note that this is easily extended using the driver system.  Another driver variable could be a custom property ranging from 0 to 1, eg stopped to full speed which can also be animated.

**An example using an `rpm` custom property.**

similarly to above make a custom property named "rpm"

[image]

Make a driver

[image]

check the use self option, this way `self["rpm"]` is our custom property.  Can get the fps from the scene. I *haven't bothered with base frame rate per example here.  Also notice this spits the "slow driver expression" warning. I don't think for simple examples like this it is an issue. I have enquired here [Use self and the slow python expression](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/use-self-and-the-slow-python-expression) .*

The expression

```
pi * frame * self["rpm"]  / (30 * fps)
```

Now I can adjust the custom property to spin the cube around Y (where i stuck the driver) at the designated rpm.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

If you want it to increase your rotation speed try changing the frame rate to a faster setting and adjust your animation to suit it.

Comment: This would not be a good solution as other things need to be at a certain speed too

Answer (score -3):

You can use rigid body

You just need to use "hinge" and "motor",

With that, you can set the " Angular Velocity"

You can also control the "Torgue"

Comment: This question is asking for angular control at a high rate, not how to simulate rotation