# Expression in a Transform field

Tags: animation

I was watching this HARDOPS TUTORIAL and I saw something interesting on how to rotate objects indefinitely.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsBwt40vP68

In a tutorial he entered this equation for the *Y Rotation*

```
#frames*0.015
```

The object then spins infinitely.

What does that command do?

Comment: Which HardOps tutorial? Please edit your question by using the link below your question and add the missing link.

Comment: More likely `#frame * 0.015`Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139145/15543